# Traverse through xml using duplicate data using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I am a newbie and was trying to traverse a ajax loaded xml file. I am trying to populate all the names and city from it, and if the name is common then i would just append the city for the common name.

my xml file

```
       <Info>
       <detail>
       <country>US</country>
       <name>Edward</state>
       <city>San bruno</city> 
       </detail>

       <detail>
       <country>US</country>
       <name>Edward</state>
       <city>Charleston </city> 
       </detail>
       </info>
```

I an trying to show it in a format like this

```
       Edward
       San Bruno
       Charleston
```

My jquery code looks like this

```
       $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
   url: "sheet.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('detail').each(function(){
            var Pname = $(this).find('name').text();
            $('<div class="items" id="link">                </div>').html('<Strong>'+name+'</Strong>').appendTo('#content');
            if(Pname = $(xml).find('name').each(function(){
            var city = $(this).find('city').text();
            var full = name + ","+city;
            $('<div class="items" id="link"></div>').html('<a href="'+city+'">'+city+'</a>').appendTo('#content');
            });
```

I am just not able to loop it again so that I can find the guy with same name but a different city hence placing them together according to different location. 
any Help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to modify this to work in your success function:

```
var xmlString = "<Info><detail><country>US</country><name>Edward</name><city>San bruno</city> </detail><detail><country>US</country><name>Edward</name><city>Charleston </city> </detail><detail><country>US</country><name>John</name><city>Charleston </city> </detail><detail><country>US</country><name>John</name><city>Dallas</city></detail></Info>",
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString),
$xml = $(xmlDoc),
$name = $xml.find("name");

var prevName = "";

$name.each(function() {
    var currNode = $(this);
    var currName = currNode.text(); 

    if (currName != prevName) {
        document.write(currName + "<br />");
        document.write(currNode.next().text() + "<br />");
        prevName = currName;
    } else {
        document.write(currNode.next().text() + "<br />");
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/Z6Bst/

Comment: This assumes that detail nodes for a given name will be adjacent. Can that be assumed for the XML?

Comment: @steveax You need to ask the OP. The example they post in the question should include any edge cases. In this case, one can only go by what's is posted in the question.

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to include the `@username` but my comment was directed at the OP. @RagsonWeb can it be assured that that detail nodes for a given name will be adjacent?

Comment: @jen: I tried Using it. thanks for the help. It worked when I used document.write. But when I changed it to use it in my code for appending the given details in a div. It doesn't work. i tried debugging, but it doesn;t show any error also. Can you tell me whats wrong with it.

Comment: @RagsonWeb Watch your capitalization of variables, it matters with js.  You must include jquery in the fiddle for jquery to work and `document.write` overwrites everthing. I quickly threw this together. You can use it to learn and improve on it: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/9ye9h/2/